# split the string into two variables of int and char in c language using sscanf

Tags: c, linux, scanf, embedded-linux

this is my code snippet and output. here `config_time` value I am reading from `.txt` file and its value "`15s`"(dont say that u have not initialized)and this value is user defined configuration time, thats why i am reading this value from file. I want the output in the form of `15` & `s`. that is `value=15 param= s`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fun ()
{
  char config_time[20];
  int r;
  char param;

  int value;
  printf("%s\n",config_time);
  r = sscanf (config_time, "%d%c", &value, &param);
  printf ("v= %d   p=%c \n", value, param);
}
```

*******output**********

```
"15s"
v= 1995421524   p=v
```

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: `int length = strlen (config_time);` That's undefined behaviour because `config_time` is uninitalised. What is the intention?

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mcve] and [edit] your question to show it. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: config_time value i am reading from .txt file

Comment: Then please show real and complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: A good [mcve] would at least initialize `config_time`. And preferably also replicate the problem you ask about (which your example code [doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/9hxK3Ydzs)). I'll bet the problem is in the code you don't show us. Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Depending on how you read the value from the file, you could replace this with something like `char config_time[20] = "15s";` or `char config_time[20] = "15s\n";`. Make sure you can run your simplified program and that it actually reproduces your problem. Otherwise the error is in some other part of your real program. Please also show the return value (`r`) of `sscanf`.

Comment: I can't initialize as 15s (15 seconds)  as it is user based configuration it can be any time for ex 6h (6 hours). So I am reading that value from file and copying the same to str. return value of sscanf that is r is showing 0.

Comment: Then initialise the string with the exact same value that *would* have been read from the file. Also, this is where you can deploy a debugger, the essential tool of the of the trade (along with man pages).

Comment: then also the behaviour of output is same @WeatherVane

Comment: Welcome, please modify the posted code to support that, so it can be copy/pasted, compiled and run to demonstrate the fault. The code posted is, as commented, faulty anyway.

Comment: char config_time[20]="15s";
  
  
  
  int r;
  char param;

  int value;
  r = sscanf (config_time, "%d%c", &value, &param);
  printf ("v= %d   p=%c \n", value, param); this case it is working proper but when i read from file output is not proper @WeatherVane

Comment: Please modify ***the posted code** to support that, so it can be copy/pasted, compiled and run to demonstrate the fault*. There might be enough information to guess and piece together *something like* your code, but people need to see the *exact* code. You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68358498/edit) link underneath the question.

Comment: By running your code with input "15s" I see "v= 15   p=s" as output. I see no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip the quotes

```
char param, config_time[20] = "\"15s\"";
int value;
printf("%s\n", config_time);
int r = sscanf(config_time + 1, "%d%c", &value, &param);
//                         ^^^ skip the initial quote
if (r != 2) /*error*/;
printf ("r = %d   v= %d   p=%c\n", r, value, param);
```

---

Or use literal quotes inside the *format string*: `sscanf(config_time, "\"%d%c\"", ...)`

Comment: thanks a million @pmg it is working proper now